# Make same components in for statement in Delphi

Tags: delphi, components

I want to make same components in for statement in delphi dynamically,
but it only make one component. Why?
How can I fix the following my code?

```
  for i := 0 to numberDot do
  begin
    button := TImage.Create(Self);
    try
      button.Parent := pnScroll;
      button.Height := 24;
      button.Width := 24;
      button.Name := 'button' + i.toString;
      button.Visible := true;
      imglScrollButtons.GetBitmap(0, button.Picture.Bitmap);
   finally
   end;
  end;
```

Comment: Perhaps you're creating many components, but they are one atop the other.  Try setting the Left or Top properties to different values.

Comment: @David, you should make your comment an answer.

Comment: You might also consider storing reference to these components in some list for further access. Yes it is true that they are already stored in the forms Components list, but retrieveing handle from it would probably require you to iterate trhough every component on the form before you find correct one. Storing references to specific list is especially required when you are creating other class objects or when you are not specifying owner for components.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The controls are owned. They aren't going to be leaked.

Comment: Tip: If you're not using try..finally to protect a resource, don't write it. The extra _unnecessary_ code just makes your program more difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're generating many components, but they are all on top of one another.  To see them all, give them different positions by setting the Left or Top properties.